# (Ruby on Rails active_model_serializers) How to move nested hash up one level in a 2-level deep association with ActiveModel::Serializer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-model-serializers

I have the following ActiveRecord associations in Ruby on Rails:

```
class Driver
  has_one :car
  delegate :tires, to: :car
end
```

```
class Car
  belongs_to :driver
  has_many   :tires
end
```

```
class Tire
  belongs_to :car
end
```

I have the following Serializer:

```
class DriverSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name

  has_one :car

  class CarSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id

    has_many :tires

    class TireSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
      attributes :id
    end
  end

end
```

The resulting JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Bob",
  "car": {
    "id": 1,
    "tires": [
      {
        "id": 1
      },
      {
        "id": 2
      }
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

But I want the `tires` to move up one level so that they're nested directly under `driver`. I want to leverage the serializers as-is, without using Ruby's `map` method. I know I can do this:

```
class DriverSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attribute :tires

  def tires
    object.tires.map{|t| TireSerializer.new(t)}
  end
end
```

But is there a simpler way to just move the hash up one level?

Comment: does just `DriverSerializer.has_many :tires` not work?

Comment: @SiimLiiser No, it doesn't work. It would work only if there was a `:has_many` relationship in the model itself. But since there is no such direct relationship, we can't use that in the serializer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's better to use `has_one :tires, through: :car` association for the `tires` attribute in you `Driver` model instead of delegating it to `:car`. You can then use the `has_many` option in your `DriverSerializer` for this attribute and use `TireSerializer` for its serializer.

```
class Driver
  has_one :car
  has_many :tires, through: :car
end
```

and in your Driver serializer

```
class DriverSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  has_many :tires, serializer: TireSerializer
end
```